# One algorithm example and the probability calculation of 1/n?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, algorithms, proof-explanation, computer-science

We have one algorithm that gets the input from {$k_1,...,k_n$} ($n$ - distinct numbers) and we want to read ($k_n$) by filling the variable $z$ with $k_n$ with probability $\frac{1}{i}$. At the final step of the algorithm, print $z$ as the output; in which the probability  $k_n$ is ($\frac{1}{n}$).

*This is one example.*

My question is, how is ($\frac{1}{n}$) calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood the problem, we have $n$ distinct numbers $k_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$ and a variable $z$. At each $i$-th step we read $k_i$ and with probability $\tfrac 1i$ put $z:=k_i$. Then $k_n$ is read at $n$-th step, so the probability that we put $z:=k_n$ is $\tfrac 1n$.

Comment: @user3661613 As far as I see, whether $z=k_n$ depends on the last step of the algorithm, but not on the previous steps.